# How to add custom parameter to Camel's Spring web service component

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, spring-camel

My application uses versions 2.19.0 of camel-core and camel-spring-ws. I need it to send a response message to a Client's service using Camel's SpringWebserviceComponent.

It's all pretty standard apart from the client's url, it contains a parameter at the end with no value e.g. https://client-service.com/path/index.php?protocol+web_service

I have never seen a URL like this before but the client states that the parameter on the end (after the question mark and with no value) maps to a controller in their application.

When I try to feed this into my application, I get a org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException.

I've looked through the source code of the SpringWebserviceComponent and line 129 of org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent (of which SpringWebServiceComponent extends) validates the URL parameters and throws the ResolveEndpointFailedException if any of the parameters are not valid parameters for the Spring web service component, as listed here: https://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html. Ofcourse, protocol+web_service is not a valid parameter for the SpringWebserviceComponent and so the exception is thrown.

This validation is only conducted if the SpringWebServiceEndpoint's isLenientProperties() method returns false, which it is hard-coded to do.

Can anyone suggest any other ways to make the SpringWebServiceComponent accept this url including its non-standard parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not support out of the box, you can try to extend the spring-ws component and override some of the methods that setup the endpoint and whatnot, and then add your hack for this "invalid" url that your client uses.